# Is it possible to get multiple counts using different groupings from one table in one MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, pivot-table

Let's say I'm working with a single table that contains the following:

```
building_id      brand_title        product_title       purchase_year
-----------------------------------------------------------------
2                Microsoft          Surface Pro 3       2014
2                Microsoft          Surface Pro 3       2014
2                Microsoft          Surface Pro 4       2015
2                Apple              iPad 2              2012
2                Apple              iPad 2              2012
2                Apple              iPad 2              2013
2                Apple              iPad 2              2013
```

I have two queries that return the data I want, but I need to merge these queries into a single query.  Here are the queries I have:

```
select brand_title, count(*) as brands_count from inventory
where building_id = 2
group by brand_title
order by brand_title
;
```

This returns:

```
brand_title     brands_count
----------------------------
Microsoft       3
Apple           4

select brand_title, purchase_year, count(*) as total_by_purchase_year from inventory 
where building_id = 2
group by purchase_year
order by brand_title
;
```

This returns:

```
brand_title     purchase_year   total_by_purchase_year
------------------------------------------------------
Microsoft       2014            2               
Microsoft       2015            1
Apple           2012            2
Apple           2013            2
```

But what I need is a single query that gives me this as its output:

```
brand_title     total_in_2012   total_in_2013   total_in_2014   total_in_2015   total_purchases_ever_by_brand
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Microsoft       0               0               2               1               3
Apple           2               2               0               0               4
```

Is this possible?  I'm okay with using case statements or subqueries, but I just can't quite make this work!

Comment: I'll see if I can apply that solution to what I'm working with.  Thanks!

Comment: What you want is a pivot table, so it's only up to you to apply what's there in the linked topic.